# I want to change position of my imagebutton programmatically in android

Tags: android, imagebutton

My question is that i want to change position my imagebutton which is created with the help of for-loop but they overlapping to much How to get rid off it?

```
    package com.example.applecounter;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        final Context context = this;
        int counter = 0;
        private MediaPlayer mplayer;
        private TextView txt;
        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;
        int right= 0;
        int bottom=0;
        private ImageButton bt[];

        /*Here i have my OnCreate function*/
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
            rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
            /*Here i have which creates my Imagebutton*/
            for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
                ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                btn.setId(1);
                params.width = 83;
                params.height = 80;
                //params.setMargins(10, 12, 50, 0);
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                params.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);
                rl.addView(btn);
                btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*Here i have both addview and onclicklistener*/
            }
        }
        /*Here i have OnClick view for mhy button*/
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
// Here i have switch case//
            case 1:
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
                //txt.setText("" + counter);
                //counter++;
                break;
            default:
            }
        }
    }
```

When i create imagebutton in for-loop so its overlapping too much so my questin is how randomzie psotion for each button?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this out

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);

btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: So you mean that it will set postion for both buttons ,So question is how to handle this code with multiple buttons?

Comment: You can use setId() for each button to asgn them an id and use these Ids to treat each button differently

Comment: But its still overlapping